# Puppeteer doesn't click on given element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on an element that redirects me within the same website but that doesn't seem to work.

```
async function scrapeJobs(url, next) {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector(next),
    page.click(next),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load" }),
  ]);

  await browser.close();
}

scrapeJobs(
  "https://www.capgemini.com/fr-fr/carrieres/offres-emploi/?search_term=&filter_contract_type=stage",
  ".pagination__next"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you need to resolve the `waitForSelector` Promise before clicking the button/link. This works for me:

```
async function scrapeJobs(url, next) {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const nextPage = await page.$(next);
  if (nextPage) {
    await Promise.all([
      nextPage.click(),
      page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load" }),
    ]);
  }


  await browser.close();
}
```

EDIT: Promise.all runs code in parallel, so it's probably trying to click the "next" button before it's available.